# LinqtoXML parsing RSS content:encoded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse an RSS feed using Linq to XML like so:

```
        XNamespace slashNamespace = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"; 
        XDocument rssFeed = XDocument.Load(@"http://blog.daimokuchart.com/index.php/feed/");

        var posts = from item in rssFeed.Descendants("item")
                    select new RSSData {
                        Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                        Published = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("pubDate").Value),
                        Url = item.Element("link").Value,
                        Content = item.Element("content:encoded").Value
                    };
```

However; it is having a problem with with the content:encoded item I get this error **"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name. "**

How the heck to I parse this item element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
XNamespace nsContent = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";

// ...

Content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to parse a RSS feed : the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class

More details [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/13/build-an-rss-reader-in-5-minutes/)

Comment: Basically the same thing except with a different class

Answer (score 0):

Hi i used Linqtoxml and successfully able to parse Rss feed try below code

```
public apheadlines()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent();
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            Uri rssurl = new Uri("http://ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/rss/southcinema/telugunews.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(downloads);
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(rssurl);
        }


 private void downloads(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in download");
            }
            var Rss = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
                      select new Data
                      {
                          Titles = rss.Element("title").Value.ToUpper(),
                          pubDate = rss.Element("pubDate").Value.Substring(0, 17)

                      };

            listBox1.ItemsSource = Rss;

        }
```